# remove software from /opt

Tags: 16.04, package-management, software-center, uninstall, rm

The software installed in that folder is not shown in *Ubuntu Software Center* in *installed* section. So I cannot remove it from GUI. How can I do it with terminal? How do I get the exact name of the package to be removed?

Comment: How did you install that software?

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -S /opt` to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to the opt folder by typing the following into the terminal

```
cd /opt/
```

To remove/uninstall

```
sudo rm -rf foldername
```

This does leave an icon on the application in your launcher/app menu. To remove it go to Control Center>> Look and Feel>>Main Menu. Select the uninstalled program and click the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button on the panel on the right.

Comment: That could leave artifacts. An uninstall procedure should be preferred if present.

Comment: @Rinzwind The problem is that I am yet to find an uninstall procedure that works better with applications based inside the **opt** folder. If you find one please post it.

Comment: Oh you are misunderstanding: the uninstall should in the /opt/ directory of that software. Example: `/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.1/` has a `uninstall`. The bigger installation all have one ;)

Comment: Not all of them. I just checked chrome and it don't have an uninstall file. I also looked for this when I uninstalled Genymotion.

Comment: Genymotion you start by running a binairy, it does not install. And the "help" claims there is a `--uninstall` option (ie. `./genymotion-{version}.bin --uninstall). Chrome will be a sandboxed install.

Comment: That method doesn't work anymore for unknown reasons. Believe me I tried.

Answer (score 1):

the software was not part of debian package. So the solution was to run the *uninstall* file in that folder:

```
sudo ./uninstall
```